# How to go to a new line while writing text to a RandomAccessFile in java?

Tags: java, database, randomaccessfile

I am trying to create a program where the user is able to create a database and add records to it. I am using random access files and with my current code I am able to write on the file. However, if there are other records on the file, I want the new record that the user adds to be appended at the end of the file, on a new line. Right now, it is appended at the end of the file but on the same line as the last record before it. Could you please help me alter my code to do what I am requesting.

Here is the code of enterData().

```
    public static void enterData(String fileName) {

    String temp = " ";


    try {
        RandomAccessFile OUT = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw");
        long fileSize = OUT.length();

        System.out.print("Id: ");
        try {
            Id = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        }catch (IOException e) {}


        System.out.print("Experience: ");
        try{
            experience = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        }
        catch(IOException e){}


        System.out.print("Wage: ");
        try {
            wage = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        } catch (IOException e) {}



        System.out.print("Industry: ");
        industry = reader.readLine();

        for (int i = 0; i<100 - industry.length(); i++){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(" ");
            sb.append(industry);
            industry = sb.toString();
        }

        FilePointerPosition = Id;
        OUT.seek(fileSize);

        String formatted = String.format("%20s%20s%20s%40s", Id, experience, wage, industry);

        OUT.writeUTF(formatted);

        OUT.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {}


      }
```

Comment: thank you very much, it works :) @progy_rock

Comment: Every post on Stack Overflow is intended to be useful to future visitors. So I request you to mark the answer as the **correct one** for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write the next line of text in the file in a new line, you can simply append a `newline character` at the end of every record. For this, you can **format** the **String** variable `formatted` by including a `"\n"` in the end of the format specification.

```
String formatted = String.format("%20s%20s%20s%40s\n", 
                                  Id, experience, wage, industry);
                 //notice the "\n" in the end of the String format

OUT.writeUTF(formatted);
```

This will take the cursor in the file to a new line after writing the contents of `formatted` just as the `System.out.println()` method takes the cursor to a new line on the VDU after flashing the output.